# Adding Bootstrap to layout page does not affect to view pages in asp.net MVC 4

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-mvc-4

I have added bootstrap to MVC 4 project as demonstrate in following  [Post](http://www.mytecbits.com/microsoft/dot-net/bootstrap-with-asp-net-mvc-4-step-by-step)

But my layout did not arrange as i expected.
I have added the required files to the mentioned folders,
and my `BundleConfig.cs` file s follows

```
bundles.IgnoreList.Clear();
            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include("~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));
            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/bootstrapjs").Include("~/Scripts/bootstrap.js"));
            bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/bootstrapcss").Include("~/Content/bootstrap.css"));
```

and then i have added new page as new layout and named it as

```
UserLayout.cs
```

my new layout page is as follows

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>@ViewBag.Title - My ASP.NET MVC Application</title>
    <link href="~/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />

    @*<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Content/Site.css" type="text/css" />*@
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/bootstrapcss")
    @*@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")*@
</head>
<body>
 <div class="container-fluid" style="background-color:azure;">
        <div class="row-fluid">
            <div class="span2">
                <!--Sidebar content-->
                 @RenderSection("Sidebar", true)
            </div>
            <div class="span10">
                <!--Body content-->
                 @RenderSection("MainContent", true)
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

   @RenderBody()

    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrapjs")

</body>

</html>
```

Then i have added new view and set the Layout as my new layout page

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Dashboard";
    //Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_UserLayout.cshtml";
}
```

but when i run the application and,the out put is as a normal web page no formating is going on,
Can some one help me to sort out this ,.. thanks ,
sorry for my bad English,
Thanks in advance,

Comment: did you include the css file ? looks like the line is commented out for `~/Content/Site.css`

Comment: Shyju ,  is Site.cs is required?